# How read data from text file and write to mysql data base by Hadoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Need to write a Hadoop map reduce program.

Map:
Input is **iTunes EPF data dump file**.File contains data base record. Each row of record may be written in two or more than two lines in the file.Need to read this record from file.

Reduce:
Output is, **write to mysql data base**.

Prob:

1) In Hadoop mapping function, how to fetch a single record from the file which is two or more than two lines.And how to specify this is the value,which is corresponds to the corresponding data base file in the mapping function

- Is it possible to use regex in Mapping function as single record may be span across more than a single line.

Comment: why do you want to use map reduce for this task?

Comment: http://johnnyprogrammer.blogspot.se/2012/01/writing-to-mysql-in-hadoop.html?m=1